# Can I acces the smart card key from hardware and decrypt?

Tags: smartcard, smartcard-reader

I want to encrypt some `Data` using the encryption key from a `SmartCard`.

Is there a way to achieve this? I want to red the encryption from the card on a `linux` server and in time to make it change.

I have readed something about `OpenSC`, does it helps me in a way?

Answer (score 0):

In an asymmetric key scheme the *encryption* key is the public key, which being public is less likely (compared to the private key) to be present on the smart card. Typically there is no way to read any key from a smart card, so the only thing to do is, sending your input to the smart card, so it can perform the encryption. The I/O bandwidth is most likely the bottleneck (so encryption directly on the host is *much* faster) and asymmetric keys are not really appropriate for bulk encryption.

Yes, OpenSC would help, if your card provides the PKCS information, but you should work on your requirements before to ensure a sensible approach.

Comment: I think she does not say anything about asymmetric keys, right? She should rather use symmetric keys with a random IV attached to the encrypted message...

Answer (score 0):

You question is really lack of very important details so technically it cannot be answered at all!

But a simple one (profaned) to your question is yes - you can access a key and you can do decrypt; The more important question is what key you can access and what are you actually doing decrypting/encrypting or signing?

There is only 2 ways you can do encryption using SC:

1. perform encrypt operation (send APDU) to a different KOs (key object): RSA, ECC KO or SM key, all of them are private keys you cannot read it off the card but you can PSO (PERFORM SECURITY OPERATION);
2. do it yourself using a public key extracted from the CA object (certificate);

CA objects are stored in the public section of the card so anybody can read it and you don't need any authentication to access public section, naturally; KOs are in the private section thus you have to get access to it first by authenticating to a card (verify pin);

NB: There is a difference between encryption and signing; when you encrypt smth you (the host) use public key to do it and only the trusted side (the server) has the private key and can decrypt it. For signing it is the same key pair but the operations are reversed: you (the host) use private key to sign the data (signature) and everybody can verify (decrypt) it using the public key to validate the host authenticity.